# Strange (c++) debug issues using VS2013

Tags: c++

I have inherited a project to work on and the initial build was developed on linux. I dont know if this matters or not but thought I would share it.

In order to debug the project on a windows machine I first use the CMakeGUI on win7 to create a Visual Studio Solutions file to open the project using Visual Studio 2013 and then set the startup project and build the project I am interested in. Up till now everything is okay. Now comes the confusing part.

On load the program is suppose to read a file lets call it `in.dat` and is declared in `const char * inputFileName` this variable is then passed through a class which attempts to open then file to obtain data.

```
fstream fs;
fs.open(inputFileName.c_str(), fstream::in);
    if(!fs.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot open input file!" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
```

This where I am stumped...the file when placed in the debug folder for some reason cannot be opened i.e `fs.is_open() returns false` when I try debugging the application BUT if I cd directly into the debug folder of the project, outside of VS, and run the executable it runs as expected i.e `fs.is_open() now returns true`.

Comment: Barring a simple mistake in settings, this actually could be a case of a [heisenbug](http://catb.org/jargon/html/H/heisenbug.html) in the wild.

Comment: Did you set the working folder for the debug session? It's in the debug properties of the project.

Comment: @JasonMc92 Likely not, a heisenbug describes something pretty different.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, well, the given example is only one scenario. A heisenbug is any case where the debugger literally changes program behavior.

Comment: @JasonMc92 _"A heisenbug is any case where the debugger literally changes program behavior. "_ I well, know that. And I actually doubt this is the case here, because the problem simply is that the file path is different than expected. A heisenbug is slightly different where such systematically cases can't be caught by any logic expected.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, well, I've seen this sort of thing happen as a result of the debugger before, which is why I mentioned originally "Barring a simple mistake in settings..."

Comment: @JasonMc92 Your reference clearly states _"A bug that disappears or alters its behavior when one attempts to probe or isolate it."_ That's a different situation, as just having a wrong setup in debugging settings.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, yup, again, either A) there's a wrong setup, or B) this is an example of a heisenbug. Beyond that, we can agree to disagree.

Comment: @JasonMc92 No that's not an example (nor a matter of opinion) for a heisenbug, you misunderstood what it is. A heisenbug is the situation, when trying to **isolate** the problem for debugging ***the bug disappears***. Just changing the setup, doesn't apply here, the bug would appear as well for a release build with the same setup. You really completely misunderstood what the reference you cited means, and probably never seen a heisenbug alive in your code (lucky dude you are).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, disappears, **or alters** its behavior. Again, fine, not one here (I only said what you quoted to clarify I knew it could NOT be a heisenbug if it was a setting error.). I've seen these alive in my code, yes, twice in fact. Only once did the bug only exhibit itself in a more probe-able way when in debug mode, and once it vanished when GDB got involved. (Thank God for Valgrind.) Difference of interpretation.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious...Thanks captain! that was the issue I was unaware of this setting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your debugger's working directory defaults to your project's root directory and the binary is in the \debug subdirectory, resulting, in effect, to the path to the input file being wrong.

Set the debugger's working directory to \debug. 
Here is more info on that:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcw4dzyf(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Thanks to you and Captain Obvlious for pointing me in the right area and thanks for the link for reference